# Make icon searchable

Tags: jquery, html, datatable

I have font awesome spans however I am using data tables which have a search bar.
Here is my code:

```
<td><i class="fa fa-circle red_star"></i><i class="fa fa-circle yellow_star"></i><i class="fa fa-circle green_star" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
<td><span class='gray_star' id='<?= $p->id?>' ><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span></td>
```

Is there a way that if i type "red" in my search bar, the red star will display and if I type green, green star with show and etc?

Comment: You could use the onChange event to listen for your input to change. Then use a switch to determine the input. Then you can use the removeClass and addClass on your <i>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
$(function() {

  $("#x").on("input",function() {
    var val = this.value;
    if (["red","yellow","green"].indexOf(val) !=-1) {
      $(".star").hide();
      $("."+val+"_star").show();
    }
    else {
      $(".star").show();
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.red_star { color:red; }
.yellow_star { color:yellow; }
.green_star { color:green;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<input id="x" type="text" />
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<i class="fa fa-circle red_star star"></i>
<i class="fa fa-circle yellow_star star"></i>
<i class="fa fa-circle green_star star" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
<td><span class='gray_star' id='<?= $p->id?>' >
<i class="fa fa-star"></i></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: yes but i dont want the circles to hide at first, i want them all to display then if i use the search, it filters the color i searched on